# SceneKit: Shademodifier ignores custom global function in Xcode 7

Tags: ios, xcode7, scenekit

The [SCNShadable Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SceneKit/Reference/SCNShadable_Protocol/index.html) states that a shade modifier in `SceneKit` may contain custom global functions. However, since the update to `Xcode 7` this option seems not to work anymore. Even the Apple example from the reference page does not compile anymore. According to the error message the custom functions are simply absent from the resulting `OpenGL` shader source code, which is generated by `SceneKit`.
Does anybody know how this new limitation (or bug?) can be worked around? Maybe an additional pragma is needed?

The problem can be seen in the first example given on the [SCNShadable Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SceneKit/Reference/SCNShadable_Protocol/index.html) under "Writing a Shader Modifier Snippet".
To see the error, simply create a new `Xcode` "game" project and paste the following code at the end of `GameViewController.viewDidLoad()`:

```
  let fragmentShader =
    "// 1. Custom variable declarations (optional)\n" +
    "// For Metal, a pragma directive and one custom variable on each line:\n" +
    "#pragma arguments\n" +
    "float intensity;\n" +
    "// For OpenGL, a separate uniform declaration for each custom variable\n" +
    "uniform float intensity;\n" +
    "\n" +
    "// 2. Custom global functions (optional)\n" +
    "vec2 sincos(float t) { return vec2(sin(t), cos(t)); }\n" +
    "\n" +
    "// 3. Pragma directives (optional)\n" +
    "#pragma transparent\n" +
    "#pragma body\n" +
    "\n" +
    "//  4. Code snippet\n" +
    "_geometry.position.xy = sincos(u_time);\n"
    "_geometry.position.z = intensity;\n"

  if let material = ship.childNodes.first?.geometry?.materials.first {
        material.shaderModifiers = [SCNShaderModifierEntryPointGeometry: fragmentShader]
  }
```

Running the program gives the following error, stating that the custom identifier `sincos` is undefined:

```
SceneKit: error, failed to link program: ERROR: 0:191: Invalid call of undeclared identifier 'sincos'
```

In the error message you can also see the program which SceneKit has generated for the shade modifier. It contains everything but the definition of `sincos` which has somehow been filtered out.

Comment: Maybe show the code you're using and the specific Apple example you've mentioned.

Comment: Thanks, for the hint, @I'L'l. I have edited my question accordingly.

Comment: Very few people using SceneKit in the wild. Seemingly nobody within Apple uses it. Hence your problems with the sample. Rudimentary testing is not done, let alone documentation updates. And there's zero communication from Apple and its employees about systemic problems within it. This has lead to almost nobody taking it seriously. Probably best to think of Apple's game frameworks as a slowly evolving molasses of ideas heading towards a future where it empowers production funded by and indentured to Apple, for game developers of their choosing as they slowly become a producer of gaming content.

Comment: I have the same issue, 2 years later. Any clue on whether Apple is going to fix it?

Answer (score 5):

You should not use "#pragma arguments" for a shader modifier written in GLSL (the documentation in the SCNShadable.h header specifies that it is for metal shaders only).
So this will work:

```
uniform float intensity;

// Custom global functions (optional)
vec2 sincos(float t) { return vec2(sin(t), cos(t)); }

// Pragma directives (optional)
#pragma transparent
#pragma body

//  Code snippet
_geometry.position.xy = sincos(u_time);
_geometry.position.z = intensity;
```

Comment: How can we declare u_time within shaders.metal file for metal kit?